# Recortar un string tras segunda aparición de un carácter con PHP

Tags: php, string, substring

Tengo esta cadena en PHP:

```
$string = "8470593,3015500750,3148212797";
```

Lo que necesito es devolver los dos primeros códigos (`8470593,3015500750`) y descartar el resto de caracteres.

Sé que necesito que sea detectada la segunda aparición de la coma `","`, pero no encuentro el modo de lograrlo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedo proponer 2 alternativas:

Una con `substr()` y `strrpos()`:

```
<?php 
  $string = "8470593,3015500750,3148212797";
  echo substr($string, 0,strrpos($string,','));
 ?>
```

Esto devuelve:

> 8470593,3015500750

La otra con `strrev()` y `strstr()`:

```
<?php 
  $string = "8470593,3015500750,3148212797";
  echo strrev(strstr(strrev($string),","));
 ?>
```

Esto devuelve:

> 8470593,3015500750,

Espero que sea lo que buscas, saludos.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar `explode()` asi:

```
$string = "8470593,3015500750,3148212797";
$codigos = explode(',', $string);
echo $codigos[0] . ' ' . $codigos[1];
```

Comment: Ya lo había hecho así, pero quiero lograrlo solo con substr(). Sería posible?